# ASPXScheduler Fails to Fire Update and Delete Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, objectdatasource, scheduler

I have a `ASPXShceduler` binded with object data source. It work fine, but when I change it to past and try to delete or update `ObjectDataSource` methods are not fired. When I change if back again it works... Any idea what is the problem?

```
<dxwschs:ASPxScheduler 
                ID="AppointmentsSchaduler" 
                ClientInstanceName="AppointmentsSchaduler"
                runat="server" 
                AppointmentDataSourceID="AppointmentsDataSource" 
                ActiveViewType="TimeLine">
                <Storage EnableReminders="False">
                    <Appointments>
                        <Mappings AppointmentId="ID" Subject="Caption" Description="Note" Label="MarkAsDone"
                            Start="StartDate" End="EndDate" />
                        <labels>
                            <dxwschs:AppointmentLabel Color="255, 194, 190" DisplayName="Not Done" MenuCaption="&amp;Not Done" />
                            <dxwschs:AppointmentLabel Color="193, 244, 156" DisplayName="Done" MenuCaption="&amp;Done"  />
                        </labels>
                    </Appointments>
                </Storage>
            </dxwschs:ASPxScheduler>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried based on demo in Devexpress page? There are 3 online demo for this situation. They using a `DemoDataSource`.

[Customization - Custom ToolTip](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxSchedulerDemos/Customization/CustomToolTip.aspx)

[Miscellaneous - End-User Restrictions](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxSchedulerDemos/Miscellaneous/EndUserRestrictions.aspx)

[Templates - Resource Headers](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxSchedulerDemos/Templates/ResourceHeaderTemplate.aspx)

There are also [4 videos](http://tv.devexpress.com/#;ASPxScheduler%20Suite.product) on Devexpress TV but you should read first [ASPxScheduler documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3685) carefully.

Comment: It updates appointments even in the past. updates not more than 2 days ago data